# How can I check my balance in mining pools that dont have an login/account option? like XMRpool

Tags: mining-pools, balance

On XMRpool_eu there is no account or login, so how can I check my balance? I assume that's why there is the "Your Stats & Payment History", on the home page, but it doesn't work for me. It says "Enter Your XMR address or address@paymentID", so I though it's ok, when I put in my wallet adress, but it says just "not found". Can you help me? I started to mine yesterday, maybe I have to wait? Til when? I understand I can not see any payments yet but the worker should be find, because I am sending results to the pool. So at least I should see my stats. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

So problem solved - I did a stupid mistake. I did everything acording to this tutorial https://www.usxmrpool.com/#easy_mining_guide, which I find well done (for noobs like me), but I wanted to mine in a different pool, than the tutorial shows. When I checked the pool adress in config file, I overloocked that I didnt change it. There is a lot of **pools with similar names so be avare of it** (like xmrpool.eu and usxmrpool.com).
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You will see your starts with the pool by using the **same address as in your miner configuration**.

Note that it may take some time before first stats appear, and you will see a pending balance only after the pool finds a block in which you took part. Also, to actually receive a payment to your wallet, your pending balance must go over the pool's payout threshold, so it may take some time - depending on your hashrate and pool payout policy.

If you still don't see anything, make sure that your miner is correctly configured ie that you actually changed the mining address in the config, and that it's communicating with the pool and submitting valid shares.